# How do I migrate from MS Office 2010 to MS Office 2019?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

I have MS Office installed on Windows 10, and am planning to move to MS Office 2019. There seem to be various pieces of advise re whether this is possible without removing Office 2010 first. Can I do that AND protect all my MS Office data from 2010?

Is there not an option to install Office 2019, transfer all the files (particularly Outlook files/data), and then remove Office 2010?

Has anybody tried this? How did they do it?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Do you plan on installing a standalone version of Office 2019? I think you can either choose to upgrade Office 2010 to 2019 during installation or run them side-by-side. However Office 2019 is 64-bit by default and you can't mix that with Office 2010 32-bit

Answer (score 1):

Office *data* files, i.e. documents and templates, are stored separately from the *MS Office application* files.

First, installing a new version of Office should not affect the existing data files. You should have the installer remove the old version program files.

Second, that said, **definitely backup the existing data before installing Office 2019**. This ensures that no matter what goes wrong, no data is lost.

- [*Outlook* .pst files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/where-does-outlook-2010-store-pst-files/6d99c4e4-1761-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) are in `%appdata%\..\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.
- [Office template files](http://www.brucebnews.com/2013/04/where-are-custom-templates-stored-for-microsoft-office/) are stored in `%appdata%\..\Local\Microsoft\Templates`
- Your *Word*, *Excel*, *Access*, *Powerpoint* documents, spreadsheets, databases and presentations are likely in your *Documents* folder; hopefully you know where and can copy them.
- Finally, a safe approach is to *image* the drive just before installing the new Office version, so if the new version doen't work well on your PC, you can revert.